# How to view or query objects or results stored in cache in memcached?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5, memcached

How to view or query objects or results stored in cache in memcached server ?
Any GUI will be appreciated and welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FastoNoSQL](https://fastonosql.com/), it supports:

- Redis
- Memcached
- SSDB
- LevelDB
- RocksDB
- UnQLite
- LMDB

[image]
<sub>(source: [fastonosql.com](http://fastonosql.com/images/main.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you need the GUI, [FastoNoSQL](http://fastonosql.com/) seems to cover your needs. Alternatively, you can use `telnet` to access the server and use built-in commands to query the data manually.

For example:

- `telnet 127.0.0.1 11211` - access the server
- `stats items` - list all stored items
- `get key_name` - get a key by name (replace the placeholder with an actual key)
- `set key_name 0 60 10` - store a key by name (0 - flag, 60 - expiration time in seconds, 10 - content size in bytes)

You can read more about it in the [official Memcached Wiki](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/Commands).

Comment: can you tel me which is the fastest cache store with tagging support?

Answer (score 1):

[image: memcache view]

You can try standalone php script from http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache